# Custom MessageListener to DefaultMessageListenerContainer being overridden

Tags: spring, jms, spring-integration, spring-jms

First of all, I am a newbie in terms of Spring Integration and Spring JMS, so maybe the solution I try to adopt is not the correct one for my requirements.

I will try to explain what I am required to implement: basically, I need to place a message in a queue and asynchronously wait for an answer in another queue.

**1. Place a message in a queue:**

**My solution:**

```
<int-jms:outbound-gateway id="sendMessageOutboundGW"
                        connection-factory="jmsGatewayConnectionFactory"
                        request-channel="marshaledSendMessageJmsRequestChannel"
                        request-destination="sendMessageRequestQueue"
                        requires-reply="false"
                        reply-destination="sendMessageResponseQueue" 
                        correlation-key="JMSCorrelationID">
</int-jms:outbound-gateway>
```

--> this works fine, I can see the messages being placed in the queue

**2. Asynchronously listen for a reply message from another queue:**

**My solution 1:**

```
<bean id="messageListenerContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
<property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsGatewayConnectionFactory" />
<property name="destination" ref="sendMessageResponseQueue" />
<property name="messageListener" ref="messageListener" />
<property name="errorHandler" ref="sendMessageResponseErrorHandler" />
</bean>

<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="sendMessageInboundGW"
                                      container="messageListenerContainer"
                                      channel="sendMessageJmsResponseChannel" />
```

The custom MessageListener implements javax.jms.MessageListener.

However, it looks that the message listener I set for the messageListenerContainer is being overridden and a org.springframework.integration.jms.ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener is being used instead. I can see in the logs that the messages received are being picked up by the messageListenerContainer.

Also, with this solution I can see in the logs the following WARN message
   **The provided listener container already has a MessageListener implementation, but it will be overridden by the provided ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener.**

**My solution 2:**

```
<bean id="messageListenerContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
<property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsGatewayConnectionFactory" />
<property name="destination" ref="sendMessageResponseQueue" />
<property name="messageListener" ref="messageListener" />
<property name="errorHandler" ref="sendMessageResponseErrorHandler" />
</bean>

<int-jms:inbound-gateway id="sendMessageInboundGW"
                       container="messageListenerContainer"
                       request-channel="sendMessageJmsResponseChannel"
                       request-destination="sendMessageResponseQueue"
                       correlation-key="JMSCorrelationID" />
```

I have the same issue with this solution -- the custom MessageListener is being overridden.

Not using the custom MessageListener, I get the following error:

**org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: no output-channel or replyChannel header available**

What am I doing wrong?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Spring Integration, the message listener *is* the inbound gateway. That's why your listener bean is being overridden.

There are several solutions

- instead of wiring your listener into the container, configure a `<service-activator/>` to invoke your POJO. The reply will be routed to the gateway and sent as a reply to the inbound gateway.
- eliminate the inbound gateway altogether and handle the message yourself - use a `MessageListenerAdapter`, make your class a POJO and the adapter will route the reply.
- if you don't want to use a `MessageListenerAdapter`, your `MessageListener` is responsible for routing the reply, but I recommend the first solution above.

Comment: Gary, thank you for the explanation! It's now clear for me! I've chosen to use a MessageListenerAdapter and it works just fine.